# How to use vue-unit-test + jest in Vue3/Ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

- Environment

  vue: 2.6.11

  @vue/composition-api: 0.5.0

  typescript: 3.8.3

  @types/jest: 24.0.19

  @vue/test-utils: 1.0.0-beta.31
- Scene

  I tried using jest in the vue-composition-api, the following code:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
But I got this error:
```

[image]
    Note that I need to create a Vue in the unit test, which is obviously not what I want, but I also can't get count for ref through shallowMount